# MusixTex with Chinese Lyrics | Make title for MusixTeX piece in LaTex

Tags: pdftex, musixtex

[image]

1) This is my first attempt to use MusixTeX, while add Chinese lyrics, I don't know how to use `CJKutf8` package macro in MusixTeX.

2) So I decide to embed MusixTex in LaTex document, but thus `musixsty.sty` macro could work, I could not make Titles.

Please helps me to fix other way.

3) My work is very naive, could you tell me where could improve?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8} % Chinese input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}

%------To set page layout -------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={170mm, 257mm},
left=20mm,
top=20mm,
}
%------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
%{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\textbf{阿拉法俄梅嘎}}
\begin{music}
\nostartrule    

\def\Notes{\vnotes4\elemskip}
\def\NOtes{\vnotes5.5\elemskip}
\def\NOTes{\vnotes6.2\elemskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
%\geometricskipscale
\normalmusicsize
\staffbotmarg=3.5\Interligne
\stafftopmarg=3.5\Interligne

\instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
\interinstrument=16\internote
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44} % 2/4 meter chosen
\generalsignature{-1}
\scale{1.0}
\nobarnumbers

\setlyrics{text}{我 要 以 感 谢 进 入 你 的 门 ,   我 要 以 赞 美 进 入 你 的 院 ， 在 你 的 门 内 有 佳 美  的 果 子 ， 在 你 院 中 有 威 严 荣 光 我 要 以 感 谢 进 入 你 的 殿 ， 我 要 以 赞 美 靠 近 你 身 旁 ， 在 你 的 殿 中 有 满 髓 的 肥 甘 ，  在 你 身 旁 我 要 放 声 歌  唱  你 名 是 阿 拉 法 你 名 是 俄 梅 戛 你 是  创  始 成 终 的 耶 和 华 从 春 秋 到 冬 夏 从 海 角 到 天 涯 我 要 欢 呼 哈 利 路 亚  }
\assignlyrics1{text}


\startpiece
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{c}\en
\bar
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large F}\Qqbu hhhh\en
\NOtes\Dqbu hj\qa i\en
\bar
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large Dm}\cu{h}\en
\Notes\isluru0f \cu f\en
\NOTes\tslur0f \hu f\en
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{c}\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large Gm}\Qqbu gggg\en
\NOtes\Dqbu gi\qa h\en
\bar
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large C}\cu{f}\en
\Notes\isluru0c \cu c\en
\NOTes\tslur0c \hu c\en
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{c}\en    
\bar
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large F}\Qqbu hhhh\Qqbu hggg\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large Bb}\cu{h}\en
\Notes\isluru0i \cu i\en
\NOTes\tslur0i \hu i\en
\Notes\Dqbu ih\en
\bar
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large Gm}\cu g\en
\NOtes\qu g\en    
\NOTes\Dqbu dd\qu e\en
\Notes\cu f\en
\bar
\NOTesp\zcharnote{p}{\large C7} \hup g\en
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{c}\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large F}\Qqbu hhhh\en
\NOtes\Dqbu hj\qa i\en
\bar
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large Dm}\cu{h}\en
\Notes\isluru0f \cu f\en
\NOTes\tslur0f \hu f\en
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{c}\en
\endpiece    

\startpiece
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large Gm}\Qqbu gggg\en
\NOtes\Dqbu gi\qa h\en
\bar
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large C}\cu{f}\en
\Notes\isluru0c \cu c\en
\NOTes\tslur0c \hu c\en
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{c}\en
\bar
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large F}\Qqbu hhhh\Qqbu hggg\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large Bb}\cu{h}\en
\Notes\isluru0i \cu i\en
\NOTes\tslur0i \hu i\en
\Notes\Dqbu kk\en
\bar
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large F}\cu j\en
\NOtes\qu h\en
\Notes\Dqbbu gh\en
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large C7}\cu i\en
\NOtes\qu h\en
\Notes\cu g\en
\bar
\NOTesp\zcharnote{p}{\large F} \hup f\en
\Notes\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu{f}\en
\endpiece

%%%%%%
\startpiece
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large Bb}\Qqbl kkki\en
\NOtesp\qup i\en
\Notes\cu f\en
\bar
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large Am}\Qqbl jjjh\en
\NOtesp\qup j\en
\Notes\cu h\en
\bar
\NOtes\zcharnote{p}{\large Gm}\qu g\en
\NOtes\Dqbu gh\en
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large C7}\cu i\en
\NOtes\qu h\en
\Notes\cu g\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\NOtes\zcharnote{p}{\large F} \qu h\en
\NOtes\zcharnote{p}{\large Bb} \qu i\en
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large C} \qu j\en
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large F}\raise-2\Interligne\rlap\ds\en
\Notes\cu f\en    
\bar
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large Bb}\Qqbl kkki\en
\NOtesp\qup i\en
\Notes\cu f\en
\bar
\NOTes\zcharnote{p}{\large Am}\Qqbl jjjh\en
\NOtesp\qup j\en
\Notes\cu h\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\NOtes\zcharnote{p}{\large Gm}\qu g\en
\NOtes\Dqbu gh\en
\Notes\zcharnote{p}{\large C7}\cu i\en
\NOtes\qu h\en
\Notes\cu g\en
\bar
\NOTesp\zcharnote{p}{\large F} \hup f\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{CJK}    
\end{document}
```