# Please share and show your best MusixTeX work

Tags: pdftex, musixtex

Long time want to learn MusixTeX, finally make one step, see my work as [Chinese Lyrics Song with Chords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417265/musixtex-with-chinese-lyrics-make-title-for-musixtex-piece-in-latex).

MusixTeX offical tutorial is very short, noly 100 pages, the examples contain music pieces are too professional for me, I simply want some examples like a level of a self-taught guitar player often uses.

It's sad that very few examples found on the Internet. If you have any good work, please share generally here!